# Is it ok to start a bounty on an entry in a topic challenge?

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge, bounty

Today @jafe started a bounty on a question of mine.

I am happy that this happened, of course (by the way, a +500 bounty is a lot). The potential problem is that the question is an entry in the 45th fortnightly topic challenge: Flags.

I don't want my question to be upvoted or viewed more than the other entries just because it has a bounty attached to it. Isn't it better if we just wait until the challenge finishes before starting such bounties? What do you think?

Comment: *"I don't want my question to be upvoted more"* I suppose the opposite applies when starting a bounty on a low quality post.

Comment: Ironically this meta question attracted my view/vote much more than any bounty would have

Comment: @riskymysteries I don't get the point in your comment. I don't think Jafe considers it a low quality post, otherwise they would not have started the bounty. I don't think my question is bad either, I just did not want it to be undeservedly recorded as one of the most viewed and voted posts in the challenge.

Comment: @ferret sorry about that, it's the so-called Streisand effect. I removed the links

Comment: @melfnt I didn't downvote anything. I don't think your question is bad.

Comment: @riskymysteries can you please explain your first comment?

Comment: @melfnt Well, you said "I don't think my question is bad" when I didn't mention anything about it being bad.

Comment: @riskymysteries I meant your very first comment: ***"
"I don't want my question to be upvoted more" I suppose the opposite applies when starting a bounty on a low quality post."*** I don't understand it

Comment: @melfnt I'm pointing out that the *"I don't want my question to be upvoted more"* should actually be *"I don't want my question to be voted on more"*.

Answer (score 7):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with this.

At least the way I see it, the fortnightly topic challenges are *not a competition* - they're more of a prompt to get puzzle ideas flowing. The "most upvoted"/"most viewed" statistics are more of a curiosity, not a 'winner' of the challenge. (Plus, both votes and views are already skewed by HNQ. So even if we *did* want to declare a winner, neither would be a particularly good way to do so.)

Comment: *both votes and views are already skewed by HNQ*. What is HNQ?

Comment: @ΛRYΛN HNQ is "Hot Network Questions", the list of questions on the bottom of the sidebar. If a post gets popular enough, it's shared there, and then it gets a lot more views and votes.